# How do we know ZFC can interpret every mathematical concept?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Even though ZFC is a first-order theory, it can interpret properties that are not first-order in a different language. For instance, in the language of graphs, the property of a graph being finite is not first-order expressible. But in any model of ZFC, we can find a set corresponding to the set of all finite graphs.

Yet how can we know that *every* mathematical concept can be interpreted in ZFC? Could there not exist some property or object in the literature which can not be represented in a model of ZFC? Do we just work from the assumption that ZFC can interpret everything -- or are there good reasons to believe so?

Comment: Isn't it the case that the category of groups **Grp** can't be represented in ZFC, because you would want the objects (groups) to form a set, and in ZFC there is no set of all groups. To make category theory work in ZFC you have to restrict **Grp** to only talk about the groups in some particular universe of discourse. But you can do category theory without this restriction and category theorists often do.

Comment: What does $ZFC$ stand for?

Comment: @Dominique - set theory: [Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms plus the Axiom of Choice, or $\mathsf {ZFC}$.](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/index.html#AxiZFC)

Comment: Or: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFC .   Also possibly useful: [Common acronyms used on main and meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3012/25554)

Comment: It can't, interpret everything. Proper Classes, sets of Dogs, donkeys, etc... Whether it can interpret everything within the domain of mathematics is something for current and future mathematicians to decide. It really depends on what we consider within our realm of mathematical discourse. Arguably, the existence of independence results for things like CH is some evidence that ZFC actually isn't "interpreting" CH correctly. If you believe that the Continuum Hypothesis Should be provable.

Comment: There's also the possibility that ZFC is  inconsistent. And then, it certainly isn't interpreting everything correctly.

Comment: I don't know why I chose **Grp** as my example when **Set** was just as correct and illustrates the same idea with fewer unnecessary details.  Just replace “group” with “set” in my comment.

Comment: Your question in the title is hard to answer since it is closer to an empirical fact or slogan, but your example is easy to justify: It is due to the power set axiom. Power set axiom allows us to express higher-order objects within set theory.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. Maybe my question was ill-formed, since we know ZFC can not interpret all of mathematics. The incompleteness theorem tells us there are some statements that we know are true, but no proof can be formalized in ZFC. So we assume only a weaker statement, that ZFC interprets "most" of mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

Your question may be conflating two distinct notions of first-order, which may contribute to your puzzlement.  First, a system such as Peano Arithmetic is a first-order theory in the sense that its axioms only quantify over "numbers".  Similarly, you can have statements over $\mathbb R$ that quantify only over elements thereof (rather than subsets of $\mathbb R$, for example).  That would be the first sense of "first-order".  A claim that most of mathematics could be interpreted this way would indeed be very novel (and implausible).

On the other hand, there is a much vaster sense of "first-order" when we speak of ZFC, in the sense that it can quantify over any elements of the cumulative hierarchy, such as for example over elements of the [traditional superstructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_(mathematics)#In_ordinary_mathematics).  That's a lot of interpretive power, indeed.  Certainly, finiteness (and finite graphs) can be handled in ZFC; this simply means a correspondence with an element of $\mathbb N$ (which is defined as the least inductive set).